# 2 label inside td alignment

Tags: html, css

Am having 2 label inside a td and am trying to make the alignment work

Is it possible ?

Here is Fiddle for the same explaining issue and how i need.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjagana/KHAJz/1/)

```
 <tr>
        <td><label >Some Label Test:</label><label>Some Label Test:</label></td>
    <td>
        <label >Some Label Test:</label>
        <label >here is the long test which exceeds the width and comes to second line but i want it like it should start below after test: instaead from some</label></td>
 </tr>
```

Am looking for second label inside  if the length is long it is coming to next line and starts from where the second label has started.

Comment: where do you want to align them? left, right or center?

Comment: @OliverMGrech left would be fine ! but am looking exactly how to avoid starting from first!

Comment: and you want them to be neatly under each other? (unlike the jsfiddle, with text overflowing from the start of line?)

Comment: also.. I would avoid using tables for this task... considering DIVs?

Comment: can you use ID's and class's?

Comment: @OliverMGrech Ya i have added in second table of fiddle how i need it ? but using the label concept! ya just the existing dynamic design am trying to chasnge :)

Comment: @Keith yes. Any suggestions?

Comment: real simple with classes and ID's, give me a sec

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple div usage of how to get what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/KHAJz/3/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="first">Some Label Test:</div>
    <div class="first">Some Label Test:</div>
    <div class="first">Some Label Test:</div>
    <div class="text">here is the long test which exceeds the width and comes to second line but i want it like it should start below after test: instead </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    width:700px;
    height:60px;
    display:inline-block;

}

.first{
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.text{
    width:300px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

What you do is make a container that holds everything together so that the tables or divs don't go everywhere.

Comment: Exact o/p but i need in format as given in My Fiddle. and you dont need inline block in ur code.div is a block element

Comment: you don't have to have inline-block but if you want them inline, it will make sure it stays inline

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want (or cant) change your DOM,
just add this to your **CSS**

```
label
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

See this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/KHAJz/4/)

But if you can change your DOM, I'd recommend you to leave the Table layout and reconstruct your layout with `div`s. -like in Keith's answer.